# Android WebView call JavaScript function from Java

Tags: javascript, java, android, webview

I am trying to call a JavaScript function from Java inside an `WebView`.

Java:

```
webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
webView.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/html/chart.html");
webView.evaluateJavascript("draw();", null);
```

HTML file:

```
<html>
<head>
    Hello World!
</head>

<body>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
function draw(){
    google.charts.load('current', {'packages':['corechart']});
      google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);

  function drawChart() {

    // Create the data table.
    var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
    data.addColumn('string', 'Topping');
    data.addColumn('number', 'Slices');
    data.addRows([
      ['Mushrooms', 3],
      ['Onions', 1],
      ['Olives', 1],
      ['Zucchini', 1],
      ['Pepperoni', 2]
    ]);

    // Set chart options
    var options = {'title':'How Much Pizza I Ate Last Night',
                   'width':400,
                   'height':300};

    // Instantiate and draw our chart, passing in some options.
    var chart = new google.visualization.PieChart(document.getElementById('chart_div'));
    chart.draw(data, options);
  }
}
</script>
<div id="chart_div"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

I have tried the HTML file in a web browser. It worked fine. First only `Hello World` is displayed, after calling `draw()` from the console the chart appears.

Comment: On your java code, you must use this too in order to have your js running: `webview.getSettings().setDomStorageEnabled(true);`

Comment: Did not solve the problem. Thank you anyway.

Comment: Try first to run `draw()` automatically on your html, say `onLoad` for example (or simply take the contents off the function, making the javasvript run standalone). Then, if everything works fine, try draw() invoked by a link. If all is ok, you reimplement the original goal.

Comment: When I take the JavaScript code out of the function everything is working. Same when function gets invoked by a link..

Comment: So your code is right. It's only the case of finding a way to input console values while using a webView. Try doing a post or get (using an html form).